# jquery animate opacity sudden display instead of smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to animate some tab contents I've made. It works smoothly when fading the content out, but fading it in doesn't. The content just appears suddenly instead of fading in.

Please check my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/rqsJ8/2/

I've tried everything I can think of, but I can't figure why this is happening.

Please enlighten me.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/rqsJ8/25/

Changed to use fadeIn and fadeOut.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the version with a new code and saved it on fiddle and here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/rqsJ8/61/

Answer (score 0):

you didn't probably mention a time for speed..

```
tabContent.animate({ opacity: 0 }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }, speed );
```

Comment: No, even when I add a timing, it's the same result... It doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your effort @Ashok Raj